# Leetcode : 187 Repeated DNA Sequences in C

Tags: c

I have been trying to solve the Leet code 187 Repeated DNA sequence in C . I know its easier to implement in C++ using hash . But I have been unsuccessful creating one in C.

Question from Leet code for refernce.

> "All DNA is composed of a series of nucleotides abbreviated as 'A',
> 'C', 'G', and 'T', for example: "ACGAATTCCG". When studying DNA, it is
> sometimes useful to identify repeated sequences within the DNA.
>
> Write a function to find all the 10-letter-long sequences (substrings)
> that occur more than once in a DNA molecule."

Input: s = "AAAAACCCCCAAAAACCCCCCAAAAAGGGTTT"
Output: ["AAAAACCCCC","CCCCCAAAAA"]

All I am trying to do is , split the string into 4 parts of 10 size each and the last string would be size 2 (which I am ignoring currently) and store in 4 different buffers and compare them to check if the string appears more than once.
Since I have used 4 different buffers to store this , I am not sure how to do this comparison in a loop or is there any other option to write a better one.

```
void dna(char * s)
{
      char *ptr;
      int masksize = 10;    
      ptr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
     char substring1[10];
     char substring2[10];
     char substring3[10];
     char substring4[10];


    strncpy(substring1, s, 10);
    strncpy(substring2, s+10, 10);
    strncpy(substring3, s+20, 10);
    strncpy(substring4, s+30, 2);
     

}
```

Thanks

Comment: But the substrings can start at any offset, not only at multiples of 10, no? One approach would be to create an array of pointers into the string `[&s[0], &s[1], ..., &s[strlen(s) - 10]]`, sort that and report adjacent strings whose first 10 characters match.

Comment: Yes substring can start at any offset. Array of pointers for the substring you mean ?

Comment: [Yes.](https://ideone.com/oQbypJ)

Comment: Are you only asking for another solution? You can find those on the very website you found this problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/repeated-dna-sequences/discuss/?currentPage=1&orderBy=most_relevant&query=C

Comment: Stack Overflow is for specific questions, and there is no specific question in this post. For challenge exercises like this one, you are supposed to **think** about the problem and what it truly requires. Just throwing whatever you know about programming at it is not the right approach. Each character in the sequences is either A, C, G, or T. How many bits does it take to represent that? How many bits does it take to represent a sequence of ten of them? How can you remember which sequences of ten you have seen?…

Comment: … How can you maintain the representation of the last ten characters seen as you iterate through the string? Figure out solutions and implement them yourself—that is the point of these challenges. Come to Stack Overflow when you have a specific problem, not when you need general ideas for solutions.

Comment: I am trying to come with my own solution. I am facing issue in comparison of the strings I have stored in the buffer. I understand my question was misleading at the top and I have changed it now. But  I am asking is the for the string comparison of the buffers.  Not a complete solution .

Comment: @M Oehm Thanks for the answer. That helped a me a bit .

Comment: If you want to manage four strings of length ten programmatically, create an array for four strings of length ten: `char x[4][11];`. Note each element must have 11 elements to allow for the terminating null character, unless you write code that works with fixed arrays of ten characters instead of with strings. (Your existing code with `strncpy` is wrong because the null terminator is neglected.) Once you have the array, you can write loops that iterate through the elements, comparing them. However, this is the wrong track; it will not solve the challenge problem.